# Сложная сортировка в Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, yii2, mysqli

У меня есть таблица с объектами objects

Так же есть различные услуги (трансфер, питание, доп. услуги) соответственно
transfer, eat, dops

Связь между объектом и услугами осуществляется через промежуточные таблицы соответственно:
transfer_for_objects, eat_for_objects, dops_for_objects

К объекту может быть закреплены 3 услуги, а может быть и ни одной.
Задача такова: отсортировать объекты по количеству прикрепленных услуг в порядке убывания. У кого-нибудь есть какие то предположения как реализовать?

Answer (score 0):

1. Можно сделать выборку с 3мя `join` , которая будет агрегировать в виртуальное поле сумму услуг привязанных к конкретному объекту, в последствии по этому полю сделать `orderBy('field_name', 'desc')` приблизительный пример.

   `SELECT *, COUNT(tfo.id) + COUNT(efo.id) + COUNT(dfo.id) AS services_total_count FROM objects AS obj JOIN transfer_for_objects AS tfo ON tfo.obj_id = obj.id JOIN eat_for_objects AS efo ON efo.obj_id = obj.id JOIN dops_for_objects AS dfo ON dfo.obj_id = obj.id WHERE 1 ORDER BY obj.services_total_count`
2. Как и в первом варианте - только считать сумму не в mysql, а например сделать просто выборку по объектам с данными о кол-ве услуг, в последствии пройтись по массиву в ответе в помощью данной функции http://php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php
   Выбор метода скорее лежит в плоскости быстродействия.